# Android Studio with Jenkins Integration

Tags: android-studio, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cd

I guess many of you have performed here continuous integration of Jenkins with Android Studio.

I have performed the following steps:

1. Created a project from Android Studio.
2. Created a repository in GitHub.
3. Pushed the code base into the Github.
4. Configured Jenkins.

Now, my target is that whenever I perform some checkin operation of the Android code into the Github, then automatically Jenkins will create a build on the latest codebase.

I already have downloaded the necessary plugins that are required for Jenkins.

Can anybody tell me step by step how can I achieve the same, since I am not sure, how Jenkins will get the apk file that is getting created once Jenkins performs the build operation on the new codebase?

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question, and may of no use for questioner, but it may help others looking for solution.

If you are looking for apk file then it is available in build path of workspace.

It looks like you are interested in CD part, then you can use "Google Play Android Publisher". It enables Jenkins to manage and upload Android app files (AAB or APK) to Google Play. please refer to following doc help from Jenkins:

https://plugins.jenkins.io/google-play-android-publisher/